# SSL_connect for non blocking socket for sheets.googleapis.com

Tags: google-api, openssl

The following approach for connecting an https page with OpenSSL seems to work for most pages, but not for sheets.googleapis.com.

```
 // initialize OpenSLL
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());


// create context
SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);

wstring strHostname = L"sheets.googleapis.com";
wstring strPort = L"443";

SOCKET s = http_server_connect(strHostname, strPort);

// make socket non blocking for the timeout
unsigned long mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &mode);

SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, (int)s);

int res = SSL_ERROR_NONE;

while ((res = SSL_connect(ssl)) != 1)
{
    int error = SSL_get_error(ssl, res);

    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(s, &fds);

    switch (error)
    {
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
        select(int(s + 1), &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
        select(int(s + 1), NULL, &fds, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
        printf("SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL\n");
        break;
    }

}
```

Running this code the first `SSL_connect` shows the expected `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and the second call does not show and error. However by checking the connection with Wireshark you see, that the server is resetting the connection. Using a blocking socket works without any problem.

I'm aware that there is a question with almost the same content which was answered by the code above, but this does not work for the google api page for any reason. Does anybody have a hint how to overcome this problem.

I've tested it on various OpenSSL versions including the latest 1.1.1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have figured out the issue. I have to set the hostname for the ssl connection by `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`.

The interesting thing is that this information seems to be cached. After Removing the command later on, the code still works.